# Memory leak in jsdom when trying to render page through server side rendering

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-leaks, jsdom

```html
const jsdom = require( 'jsdom' );
const JSDOM = jsdom.JSDOM;
const Utils = require( '../helper/utils.js' );

module.exports = {
 /**
  * Controller method to render a HTML string.
  *
  * @param {Object} request Object that holds http request information.
  * @param {Object} response Object that holds http response functions.
  */
 render: ( request, response ) => {
  const resourceLoader = new jsdom.ResourceLoader( { strictSSL: false } );
  const virtualConsole = new jsdom.VirtualConsole();

  // Define JSDOM configurations.
  const options = {
   contentType: 'text/html',
   referrer:    request.body.originUrl,
   resources:   resourceLoader,
   runScripts:  'dangerously',
   url:         ( request.body.originUrl + request.body.relativeUrl ),
   // virtualConsole: virtualConsole.sendTo( console ),
   beforeParse( window ) {
    // Sync all browser related global properties with Node global properties.
    Utils.syncGlobalProperties( window );

    // Add event listener to know when page is fully loaded.
    window.addEventListener( 'load', async function ( e ) {
     // Set SSR Flag to indicate the page is Server-Side rendered.
     Utils.setSSRFlag();

     const renderedHtml = dom.serialize(); // eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define

     dom.window.close(); // eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define
     dom = null; // eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define
     global.window = null;
     global.document = null;

     // if ( process.memoryUsage().heapUsed > 200000000 ) { // memory use is above 200MB
     //  global.gc();
     //  await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, 500 ) );
     // }
     // setInterval( function () {

     //  //only call if memory use is bove 200MB
     //  if ( process.memoryUsage().heapUsed > 200000000 ) {
     //   global.gc();
     //  }

     // }, 10000 );

     //Return response after page load.
     response.send( renderedHtml ); // eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define
    } )
   },
  };

  // Render HTML and Javascript using JSDOM.
  let dom = new JSDOM( request.body.html, options );
 },
}


//syncGlobalproperties function
syncGlobalProperties: window => {
  global.window = window;
  global.document = window.document;

  // Declare some matchMedia attributes and functions to avoid undefined error.
  global.window.matchMedia = global.window.matchMedia || function () {
   return {
    matches:        false,
    addListener:    function () {},
    removeListener: function () {},
   };
  };

  //Declared scrollTo function to avoid undefined error.
  global.window.scrollTo = () => {};

  //Declared requestAnimationFrame function to avoid undefined error.
  global.window.requestAnimationFrame = () => {};

  // Assign common properties to node global variable.
  Object.keys( window ).forEach( key => {
   if ( ! ( key in global ) ) {
    global[key] = window[key];
   }
  } );
 },
```

I'm trying render react code through ssr using jsdom, but the heap memory keeps increasing till 1.5gb and then crashes giving console message as "JavaScript heap out of memory". I tried mannualy injesting the garbage collector but that also doesn't seem to work.
Tried a couple of things:

```
1. dom.window.close(); 
    dom = null; 
    global.window = null;
    global.document = null;
2. if ( process.memoryUsage().heapUsed > 200000000 ) {
      // memory use is above 200MB
       global.gc();
       await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, 500 ) );
     }
3. setInterval( function () {
    //only call if memory use is bove 200MB
    if ( process.memoryUsage().heapUsed > 200000000 ) {
        global.gc();
    }
 }, 10000 );
```

None of the above seems to be working.

Comment: Can you please post [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which demonstrates the memory leak? Chances are you're assigning the rendered string to a variable or into a map which isn't being deleted.

Comment: I can post my entire code but reproducing is an issue

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong (unless syncGlobalProperties) does something weird. If you just want to render react code on the server, have you tried using https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html?

Comment: Haven't tried that @BennettHardwick...thanks for the info...But any idea on how i can avoid the memory leak ?

Comment: I'll add the sync global properties function as well

Comment: You should try and refactor your code not to use the sync globals method, JSDOM suggest that doing that is an antipattern: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/wiki/Don't-stuff-jsdom-globals-onto-the-Node-global

Comment: Okay thanks I'll look into that

Comment: @Kavyanagendra Did you solved this problem?